# Is there a tree selection option for files & directories in install4j?

Tags: windows-7, install4j

I have a zip file from which I want to extract only some files that I would select. Since the selection is dynamic, I figured that the best way to select these files since they are inside folders that could be nested inside other folders, would be a selection tree. Unfortunately, I haven't found such option in install4j, and I haven't found any 3rd party tool that could do the trick.

So far, all what I have been able to found is treecopy : (http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/treecopy/) ,a tool that copies my extracted folder, and keeps its structure, but without copying any file. I used it by a "Run executable" action for which I pass the two folders as arguments, that been said I want to know if there is any tree selection filee option in further versions of install4j or any 3rd part tool, that I can use as an action.

By the way I am using, install4j 5.1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 6, there is no such form component in install4j. You can develop such a form component yourself. See the files `SampleFormComponent[BeanInfo].java` in the "customCode" sample project. As a base, you could use

http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/CheckBoxTree.html

Jide commons is [open source](https://github.com/jidesoft/jide-oss) and you can add the Jide commons JAR file on the Installer->Custom code & Resources step together with the implementation of the form component.